# Try to implement post favoris on my application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm new on rails, I work on an application and I try to implement favoris for the users post, I use [this tuto](https://codediode.io/lessons/1788-hearting-liking-or-starring-with-rails), I don't have error, but it doesn't work :

show.html.erb :

```
<h1><%= @post.user.fname %> <%= @post.user.lname %>, <%= @post.user.age %> ans</h1>
<h2>Coach d'<%= @post.user.mother_tongue %></h2>
 <p><%= @post.user.spoken_languages.map(&:name).sort.join(", ") %></p>
 <p><%= @post.price %>€ / jour</p><br>

 <p> <%= @post.user.fname %> en quelques mots :<br>
     <%= @post.content %></p>

 <p>HEBERGEMENT :<br>
  <%= @post_attachments.build %></p>

 <%= link_to "Contacter #{@post.user.fname}", '#' %><br><br>

 <%= render partial: 'hearts/button', locals: { post: @post } %><br><br>

 <% if @current_user == @post.user %>
   <%= link_to "Editer", edit_post_path(@post) %>
   <%= link_to "Supprimer", @post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Êtes-vous sûr?" }%>
 <% end %>
```

_button.html.erb :

```
<% if current_user.heart?(@post) %>
  <%= link_to "Unheart", unheart_path(post_id: @post.id), remote: true, method: :delete  %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to "Heart", heart_path(post_id: @post.id), remote: true  %>
<% end %>
```

hearts_controller.rb :

```
class HeartsController < ApplicationController

  respond_to :js

  def heart
    @user = current_user
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @user.heart!(@post)
  end

  def unheart
    @user = current_user
    @heart = @user.hearts.find_by_post_id(params[:post_id])
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @heart.destroy!
  end
end
```

heart.rb :

```
class Heart < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user

  validates :user_id, uniqueness: { scope: :post_id }
end
```

post.rb :

```
  has_many :hearts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :hearts
```

user.rb :

```
  has_many :hearts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :posts, through: :hearts
```

Thanks in advance for your help

heart.js.erb :

```
$('div#<%= dom_id(@post) %>').html('<%= j render partial: "button", locals: {post: @post} %>');
```

unheart.js.erb :

```
$('div#<%= dom_id(@post) %>').html('<%= j render partial: "button", locals: {post: @post} %>');
```

erreur :

> ```
> ActionController::RoutingError (undefined method `respond_to' for HeartsController:Class
> Did you mean?  respond_to?):
> ```

Comment: _"I don't have error, but it doesn't work"_ - What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh, just nothing happen when I click on heart...

Comment: Please post your server logs if any.

Comment: Instead of posting the errors and stack trace in comments, please add to the question for everyone to see.

Comment: As per the error, your `@current_user` is `nil`. Looking at your _\_button.html.erb_, i think you need to change it to `current_user` in _show.html.erb_ too.

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that you used `remote: true` on your buttons in *_button.html.erb*. This causes the action to be performed by ajax. That means you won't see anything after clicking the button. Inspect your server logs to see if the request actually came through.

To handle the response to your remote-request frontend-wise, you would need some javascript in place. Or just remove the remote-flag.

More info: [guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#remote-elements](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#remote-elements)